# Change text on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several div with the same class. And I have a text field that will display the title of the current div.

```
<p class="displayTitle"></p>
<div class="scrollDiv" data-title="div1">...</div>
<div class="scrollDiv" data-title="div2">...</div>
<div class="scrollDiv" data-title="div3">...</div>
```

I'm trying to change the `displayTitle` to the title of a `scrollDiv` every time the window scroll to that div.

Here is my initial code

```
function setScrollingText() {
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        var $aBlk = $(".scrollDiv");
        var title = $aBlk.data("title");
        console.log(title);
    });         
};
```

The problem that I have with this code is that I only able to get the title of first div even I scroll the window to the second or third div.

Any suggestion would help. Thanks.

Comment: you cannot get the current viewing element from js. but you can try it by playing around with offset heights. get every elements heights and identify current element by current position of viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on article [Detecting if an element is in the Viewport : jQuery](https://medium.com/talk-like/detecting-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-jquery-a6a4405a3ea2) published on medium.

To check if an element is in the viewport, we need four values.

- elementTop : Top position of the element.
  offset function is used to find the position relative to parent
  element(body in this case) and top refers to the distance from the
  top.
- elementBottom: Bottom position of element
  To find the bottom position of element we have to add the height of
  the element to the elementTop variable. Luckily for us jQuery
  provides a method called outerHeight which allows us to find the
  height of element including border, padding and optionally padding.
- viewportTop: Top of the Viewport
  Can be found with the scrollTop function on window object.
  Conveniently returns the relative position from the scrollbar
  position to object matched, which in this case is our window.
- viewportBottom: Bottom of Viewport
  Same as elementBottom. We add height of window to the viewportTop to
  find bottom.

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  $('.scrollDiv').each(function() {
      var title = $(this).attr('data-title');
    if (isInViewPort($(this))) {
      console.log(title);
    }
  });
});         

function isInViewPort($this) {
  var elementTop = $($this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="displayTitle"></p>
<div class="scrollDiv" data-title="div1">
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"

</div>
<div class="scrollDiv" data-title="div2">
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
</div>
<div class="scrollDiv" data-title="div3">
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
</div>
```